Genkit Retriever: Filter Collection Before Running Genkit Retriever in Firestore?
I’m working with Genkit’s retriever in Firebase , aiming to filter a collection before applying an embedding match. Specifically, I’d like to filter documents where uid equals a specific value (e.g., 123) before performing the nearest neighbour search on embeddings.
The typical way to filter a Firestore collection is like this:
where('uid', '==', 'my uid')

Here's my current setup for the retriever based on Genkit documentation. I may be missing something, or perhaps pre-filtering isn’t supported? It seems essential to be able to filter down to user-specific documents before executing the similarity search.
const firestoreRetriever = defineFirestoreRetriever({
  name: 'firestore-articles',
  firestore: getFirestore(),
  collection: 'articles',
  contentField: 'fullText',
  vectorField: 'embeddings',
  embedder: textEmbeddingGecko,
  distanceMeasure: 'COSINE',
  metadataFields: ['path']
});

This retriever is being called as follows:
const docs = await retrieve({
  retriever: firestoreRetriever,
  query,
  options: { 
    k: 1,
    limit: 10,
  },
});

Does Genkit provide a method for applying a pre-filter on a specific field (e.g., uid) within the defineFirestoreRetriever function, or would this require a workaround? Any guidance or alternative approaches would be appreciated.

Have you tried:
const docs = await retrieve({
  retriever: firestoreRetriever,
  query,
  options: { 
    k: 1,
    limit: 10,
    where: {
      uuid: '123',
    },
  },
});

The where option is mentioned in the available retriever options for Firestore vector store: https://firebase.google.com/docs/genkit/plugins/firebase#retrievers

Thanks, tested and can confirm it worked! Considering how useful this feature is, it's surprising it gets only a passing mention in the documentation and doesn't appear in any samples (although no excuses, I missed what you did not). One additional step to note: you need to deploy a new vector index via GCC.
